# How to categorize data according to the first n characters of its number?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Sorry for the confusing title, my problem is this:

I have a table of items, like this:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Number** | **Name** | **Category** |
| **2** | 100-150-135 | Mike | - |
| **3** | 150-150-133 | Joe | - |

In the same document, I have another sheet that looks like this:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Number** | **Category** |
| **2** | 100 | 1 |
| **3** | 150 | 2 |

I want the first table to check the first three characters of a number, look up the corresponding category in the second table and write that category into the third column. So "Mike" should have category 1 and "Joe" should have category 2.

I tried to do it by extracting the first three characters using `LEFTB` and then using `IFS` like so:

`=IFS((=LEFTB(A:A;3))=Sheet2!A:A ; Sheet2!B:B)`

Gives me an error `Formula parse error` . I tried to do something similar with `SWITCH` but that didn't work either. I have never worked with Sheets before, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Why are you using `LEFTB` instead of `LEFT`? Are you planning to use double bit characters? By the way, when reporting an error usually it's required to include the textual error.

Comment: Thank you. The error I got was `Formula parse error.`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include it.

Comment: Another tip, add the column and row headers (A, B, C, and 1, 2,3 respectively), so it's clear how the sample data and the formula are placed. On complex formulas it's usually asked to include a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view only.

Answer (score 0):

The "Formula parse error" usually is due to a syntax error. In this case, the formula included in the question(`=IFS((=LEFTB(A:A;3))=Sheet2!A:A ; Sheet2!B:B)`) has a syntax error:

1. The equal sign could be used as an unary operator only when it's the first character in a cell value to indicate the cell content is a formula, in other words, `(=LEFTB(A:A;3))` throws an error.

But the formula has other problems:

2. As the formula is intended to return multiple values, it's missing `ArrayFormula` function. This function usually is used as the outmost formula function, in other words, it's puts next to the equal sign and the other functions / expressions are put inside its parenthesis.
3. Open references like `A:A` might cause problems because they grab all the values from the first row to the last.

   - Adding the formula to below row 1 might cause errors because there the sheet will not have enough rows. To prevent this, one option is to use `A2:A` instead of `A:A`, another option is to use `FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))`. There are many other ways (some helpful functions `QUERY`, `ARRAY_CONSTRAINT`).
4. A comparison like `(LEFTB(A:A;3))=Sheet2!A:A` is done on a row by row basis, meaning the first value from the left side of `=` is compared with the first value of the right side, the second value from the left side of `=` is compared with the second value of the right side, and so on.

By the other hand,

- `IFS` is used when there are multiple pairs of conditions and results, but in this case there is only one, so instead `IF` should be used instead of `IFS`.
- `LEFB` is used when the text value include double-bit characters but the examples provided use regular characters (in this case numbers separated by dashes). Use `LEFT` instead.

Comment: I just tried that formula, it returns `Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (1).` I don't really understand what that means. (Should I add this error to the question as well?)

Comment: It means that the formula require more rows than sheet rows. This is caused when using A:A stile references on "simple formulas" placed on cells below row 1.

Comment: The sheet has 1700 entries, but about 50k rows, so most of them are empty anyway.

Comment: All the relevant details should be included in the question, but those additional details should be added to an existing question only if they not invalidate a current helpful answer, if you need further help, insted editing the current question post a new one. P.S. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)